# Sequence contains no elements even though it does

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I've a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Runs` but it throws `Sequence contains no elements` within my view.
I've added a `DefautIfEmpty()` to prevent this:

```
 var defaultListItemRow = table.NewRow();
            defaultListItemRow["description"] = "Er zijn geen runs beschikbaar om te kiezen";
            defaultListItemRow["runguid"] = Guid.Empty;

            model.Runs =
            from row in table.AsEnumerable().DefaultIfEmpty(defaultListItemRow)
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = row["description"].ToString(),
                Value = row["runguid"].ToString()
            };
```

Within the view I use a HTMLHelper to create a custom dropDown:

```
  @Html.FabricDropDownListFor(model => model.Runs, Model.Runs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ms-Dropdown-select", @style = "width: 100px;" }, label: "Billing-run", choosetext: "Selecteer een run...")
```

This contains a MvcHtmlString that's not null and contains the default item.
[image]

Like you can see in the printscreen `Model.Runs.Max()` returns a SelectListItem like expected.
But it still throws the `Sequence contains no elements` with the following stacktrace:

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Cloudbilling_VPS_Overzicht_cshtml.Execute() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Cloudbilling\VPS_Overzicht.cshtml:line 21
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

I'm out of ideas, who has any?

Comment: `Runs` and `CustomerRuns` are two different properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view with the `Max` exception you are using a different model property:

`Model.CustomerRuns`

The default-fallback item is applied to the `Model.Runs` property.

Apart from that, the `Max` selects `RunDate` which you don't initialize in your default item.

Comment: The exception is thrown at line 21, so that should be weird? I will look a the CustomerRuns

Comment: In line 21 is no `Max` but the stacktrace clearly shows that it's the problem. So  line 24 is causing the exception, the `foreach` would just be skipped if theres no item.

Comment: I see thx! I will look farther than the line in the exception the next time....

Comment: The stacktrace is very useful, helps you understand what it tried to do when it got the exception